# Facebook AppLinkData fetchDeferredApplinkData ReactNative

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to use the `AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData` SDK method in a React Native app. The official React Native wrapper for FBSDK - https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk - does not seem to have a binding for the same.

How can I call this method from a React Native application? Just making a call from `MainApplication.java` / `AppDelegate.m` should be sufficient?

I'm trying to solve this particular issue with the FB Ads setup:

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Following should works for *iOS* if you already have installed `react-native-fbsdk`, then in your AppDelegate.m add the next code:

```
  if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] == nil) {
    // Get user consent
    [FBSDKSettings setAutoInitEnabled:YES];
    [FBSDKApplicationDelegate initializeSDK:nil];
    [FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Received error while fetching deferred app link %@", error);
      }
      if (url) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
      }
    }];
  }
```

For **Android** you should be like this, in **MainActivity**:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    Log.d("SplashActivity", "appLinkData: " + appLinkData);
                }
            }
        );

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        Log.d("SplashActivity", "data: " + data);
```